# apps script not found error

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I had the snooze app script working on gmail for some time but it seems that after converting to google drive, the spreadsheet vanished (not in trash) and I get emails every night telling me that my script "Not Found" failed to finish successfully etc etc.

The Error message is that a server error occurred - not particularly informative and any attempt to view triggers results in the same error.

Is there any way to get rid of these messages apart from setting up some kind of filter which is counter intuitive as if I decide to run other scripts I may want to see the output.

Thanks

Darren

Answer (score 0):

Darren, can you please raise this on the Apps Script issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list? If possible, please also let us know in the issue tracker request what the email address is where you're receiving the failure notification email.